# Ruby - attempting to use Datastax cassandra driver

Tags: ruby, cassandra, datastax-ruby-driver

Am attempting to use Datastax Cassandra driver from [here](https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver).

Am running into this error: `<main>': undefined method 'cluster' for Cassandra:Module (NoMethodError)`

What I've done:

- *gem install cassandra-driver --pre*
- copy their 'quick start' code into a file
- attempt to execute it

My setup:

$ruby --version
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]

Is this version too high? Is there a cassandra driver / connector missing from my system?

---

#gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...

cassandra-driver (1.0.0.beta.3)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a documentation ("readme.md") bug. Apparently the next rev of the driver will use 'cluster' instead of 'connect' to get the first connection.

Change the offending line in the sample to 'Cluster.connect' and all is well.

Documented [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/RUBY-12).

Answer (score 0):

The docs/readme in the master branch of GitHub for the driver may document unreleased or future versions' information (if you're using a specific gem). Now there's a disclaimer on the readme.

Use the docs for the specific version of the driver/gem you're using, e.g. [beta 3](https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver/tree/v1.0.0-beta.3)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but caused by conflicting gems:

This worked:
https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver/blob/master/features/README.md

require 'datastax/cassandra'

... 
DataStax::Cassandra.cluster